# How to refresh input form after submission?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple form in my android project which sends data to the webserver. Is there any way that I can make the form refresh after a successful submission?

The code I have that handles the success or failiure message once the submit button is pressed:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
String jsonStr = result;
if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
        if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Record added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Adding record failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Can anybody explain the best way that I can implement this so that the form will refresh once the data is successfully sent?

Comment: there is no any specific way you just set "" in your form element like `EditText` control

Comment: You can empty the editext after successfully data sent.

Comment: Use the `setText()` method with a blank value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This method is used for refreshing the activity

```
public void refresh(View view){          //refresh is onClick name given to the button
  onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onRestart();
Intent i = new Intent(lala.this, lala.class);  //your class
startActivity(i);
finish();

}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I managed to integrate this into my mainActivity However it refreshes if the form submission is unsuccessful too - But it's a work in progress